# Filtering entries that appear more than once in R

Tags: r, repeat

From the following dataset, I want a count of patient IDs with more than one visit.

```
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4)
visit <- c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, visit)
mydata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additional option
`base` R

```
sum(table(mydata$pt_id) > 1)
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `count`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
   count(pt_id) %>%
   filter(n > 1) %>% 
   nrow
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  pull(pt_id) %>%
  unique %>%
  length
# [1] 3
```

With base - keep only duplicated ids, count unique values:

```
length(unique(mydata[duplicated(mydata$pt_id), ][["pt_id"]]))
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
library(dplyr)
mydata%>%group_by(pt_id)%>%mutate(count=ifelse(cumsum(n())>1,1,0))
```

If `count` is `1` then the patient had more than one visits and so on.